# How to bind a user control property?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public CategoryType Category {get; set;}
}

public class CategoryType
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And a user control for the category type:

```
[DefaultBindingProperty("Value")]
public partial class CategoryTypeControl : UserControl
{
    public class ValueChangedEventArgs
    {
        public T OldValue { get; private set; }
        public T NewValue { get; private set; }

        internal ValueChangedEventArgs(T oldValue, T newValue)
        {
            this.OldValue = oldValue;
            this.NewValue = newValue;
        }
    }
    public delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e);
    public event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged = delegate { };

    private CategoryType value;

    [Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    public virtual CategoryType Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set 
        {
            ValueChanged(this, new ValueChangedEventArgs(this.value, value));
            this.value = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

The `Customer` form has a bindingsource bound to the above `Customer` model and `Customer.CategoryType` is bound to `CategoryTypeControl.Value`. This is done in design mode and the generated code is:

```
this.categoryType.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", this.bindingSource, "CategoryType", true));
```

The problem is that the model's `CategorType` property is not being updated when the user selects a category type from the contorl.

Is this not the correct way to bind a user control property?

Comment: How do you bind the instance of Customer ? Post that code.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Simply adding a BindingSource control on the form, and select the datasource in design mode.

Comment: How Customer.CategoryType is bound to CategoryTypeControl.Value ? Maybe there is the problem? Posting that code will help.